# Video lectures on Group Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

The web is full of video lectures these days but, try as I might, I can find very little for Introduction to Group Theory. The closest I found was http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra . Are they any online introductory group theory lectures people would recommend?

Comment: Why videos? Why not a book? (I am interested, because I would always go for the book - it means I can go at my own pace, flip back if I want to see something again, etc.)

Comment: @user1729 There is of course nothing wrong with books but I find that video lectures often present material in a different and more approachable way.  You can of course pause and flip back video lectures too.

Comment: http://www.pinterest.com/mathematicsprof/ has a huge list of over a thousand math video lectures. You may find that helpful.

Comment: @Shahab It's a very nice link but are there actually any introductory group theory lectures in there? I haven't found any so far.

Comment: I found this following the trail from the above site: http://www.learnerstv.com/Free-Maths-Video-lectures-ltv590-Page1.htm I haven't seen any lecture myself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://www.youtube.com/user/LadislauFernandes Has uploaded quite a few videos on introductory group theory.

I have not watched that much of any of them though, so I can't say much about the quality (the bit I have watched seemed ok. A bit slow, but that might just be because this is not new stuff to me).

Comment: +1 for this. The video lectures from Ladislau Fernandes have helped me a lot when I was taking Group Theory. His explanations are easy to follow and he covered a lot of topics. Plus he has that soft dull voice of a grandfather teaching his grandchildren life lessons. I very much recommend his videos.

Comment: Link to the list of Group Theory lectures only: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLWbnIo7XnOkw7zZu6u3si3at21r534qIM

Comment: @tobias kildetoft's thanks for sharing link hats off to author to his effort really helpful video +1 up vote for link

Answer (score 4):

http://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra

These are some excellent videos by Harvard professor Benedict Gross. They are not specifically about group theory but they do cover group theory to certain extent.

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Richard Borcherds has a set of [online group theory lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8yHsr3EFj51pjBvvCPipgAT3SYpIiIsJ). In his own words, it's pitched at "first-year graduate or enthusiastic undergraduate" level, with an emphasis on examples rather than proofs.

Comment: What sort of graduates are doing an introductory group theory class?

Comment: @graffe: good question; it might depend upon the country - not every mathematics Bachelor's degree requires a course in group theory, although no introductory course in abstract algebra at all would be strange, at least for pure mathematicians. The possible lack of a basic course in group theory might come across as particularly odd to those for whom such a course is standard in their second or even first undergraduate year. Also, some graduate algebra courses revisit the basics, possibly at a faster pace, before introducing more advanced material.

Comment: @graffe: I also see the following description by Borcherds on the [YouTube page](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8yHsr3EFj51pjBvvCPipgAT3SYpIiIsJ) for the course: "This is an experimental online course on mathematical group theory, corresponding to about the first third of the Berkeley course 250A (introductory graduate algebra). The level is for first year graduate students or advanced undergraduates. The topics covered are roughly the parts of group theory that a mathematician not specializing in groups might find useful."

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out out any of Ben Garside's over a hundred videos? They're pretty detailed.

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAvgI3H-gclb_Xy7eTIXkkKt3KlV6gk9_

Answer (score 2):

I have recently found this [crash course in group theory](http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/%7Erichard/teaching/s2015/Group_2.pdf) online.
It is basically a good summary for anyone interested in learning the very basics of Group Theory or for reviewing some topics before going deeper into the theory.

I'd also recommend trying [Professor Macauley](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCH1cV4RtgI_N97M8jepiUzw)'s series on Group Theory. He explains things with a lot of detail, with examples and proofs, so the lessons can feel a bit long if you're only interested in getting the results/fundamentals, but they're quite good and useful, specially if you're seeing the topics for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Check this Link :

http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses.php?disciplineId=111

Not specially for group theory but Group theory relevant stuffs also there.

Comment: Link seems to be broken