# Online materials for self studying introductory abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, online-resources

I am interested in trying to self study intro abstract algebra this summer, but I am feeling that just using books may not be the best. I am interested to know if anyone has links to any free lectures on the subject, either on youtube, or elsewhere, that I could use to supplement my learning.

Thanks everyone

I think it is a little odd to mark as duplicate in this context and the question linked to was from 2013. Videos are always coming out and in fact the ones I have found below were not in that one...

Comment: Googling "abstract algebra notes" gets several good hits. Did you try this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Video lectures on Group Theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518759/video-lectures-on-group-theory)

Comment: @paulgarrett  I did not ask for notes, so I don't see your point but thanks

Comment: Then google "abstract algebra video lectures". (Re paul's comment, note that it is not obvious from your question that you wish to exclude notes from the query.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Math Doctor Bob](http://mathdoctorbob.org/Algebra.html) has many videos on topics in abstract algebra, including linear algebra, group theory, ring theory, and field theory.

Comment: That site is legit. Wow.

Comment: yea very good thanks

Answer (score 1):

This link by [LadislauFernandes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWyyysMb-oE&list=PLWbnIo7XnOkw7zZu6u3si3at21r534qIM) starts with basics of abstract algebra and goes through groups to rings and fields. He also has many lectures on linear algebra and representation theory etc.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For a lighter introduction you may want to try https://youtu.be/QudbrUcVPxk