# Benedict Gross Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I recently started watching Harvard's Abstract Algebra Course by Benedict Gross. I am not able to find his lecture notes and problem set and they are not given on the Harvard website. 
Anybody has them or knows where I can find them

Answer (score 8):

There is [a link](http://wayback.archive-it.org/3671/20150528171650/https://www.extension.harvard.edu/open-learning-initiative/abstract-algebra) on Benedict Gross's [own Harvard webpage](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gross/) to the 'old' lecture notes and assignments since they were deleted off the original webpage.

Answer (score 4):

I've found and made them available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nkqj7khal1qvc28/AADLZ7cg1TV4hhdLVzb3o-9aa?dl=0).

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search yielded me a complete list of his lectures on [infocobuild](http://www.infocobuild.com/education/audio-video-courses/mathematics/math-e222-harvard.html).

See also [here](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA7B08F1D8252DE29).

See also Jorge’s answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518759/video-lectures-on-group-theory).

Answer (score 0):

To this date, some of the links in the current answers are either broken, or only contain the lecture notes (at least I can't access the problem sets there).

For anyone looking for them, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/rnlkdbhd84d7ixd/AAA_ur8m-0oQkohLy9s_BYpFa?dl=0) is a link.