# Introductory book on Group Theory for physicists

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, physics, book-recommendation

I am looking for an introductory book on Group Theory that would be good for physicists. I am currently using [*Group Theory* by J.S. Milne,](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/gt.html) but I find it slightly hard to digest (I find it too formal for someone who isn't  from the field of mathematics).

So I'm looking for a book that would allow for a more *hands-on*, intuitive approach to Group Theory, and that doesn't require too much mathematical background for one to understand the basics.

PS: Recommendations on online courses would also be appreciated

Comment: A Course in Group Theory by John F. Humphreys is a good book for that first time in group-theory. I started with it and rapidly learnt the basics, faster than searching online "here and there".

Comment: cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518759/video-lectures-on-group-theory), and consider on line lectures by Benedict Gross based on M. Artin's _Algebra_ text

Comment: Have a look at the [PSE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/524223/66086).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [*Group Theory in a Nutshell for Physicists*  (2016, Princeton University Press)](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691162690/group-theory-in-a-nutshell-for-physicists)  by [Anthony Zee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Zee)?

I know you are focusing on physics, but try the following books!

- [*Discovering Group Theory: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics* (2016 1st ed.). CRC Press](https://doi.org/10.1201/9781315405780). By Tony Barnard, Hugh Neill.
- [*A Friendly Introduction to Group Theory*  (2017 2nd ed)](https://a.co/d/i76z7Ff) by David A. Nash.
- [*Abstract Algebra: A Student-Friendly Approach*](https://today.williams.edu/books/abstract-algebra-a-student-friendly-approach) (2017) by Laura L. Dos Reis, Anthony J. Dos Reis.

More books are recommended  [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/math/comments/7bs3yg/i_love_the_proof_and_rigorous_side_of_math_is/dpkp6eb) and [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/72k1bl/til_of_john_leray_a_french_mathematician_who/dnjlavd).

Answer (score 1):

My favorite "intuitive" book on group theory by far is ***Visual group theory*** by Nathan Carter (MAA Press), but it isn't directed to physics, and has very little on Lie groups, which figure so prominently in physics.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite intro group theory book is *A Book of Abstract Algebra* by Charles Pinter.  It is a very gentle introduction.  I can't say it has too many concepts that will be useful for physicists, but it is very readable and intuitive.  I actually found there is a link [here](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~jcohen/402/Pinter%20Algebra.pdf) in case you wanted to download it.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I found this [crash course in group theory](http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~richard/teaching/s2015/Group_2.pdf) online. It is a good crash course for anyone interested in learning the basis or reviewing them before going into something a little more deep.

It is a bit hard to find online support content for students taking an intro course on this subject, so I hope this helps.